# Xmarin: UILabel in UITableViewCell update width

Tags: xamarin.ios

My UILabel in UITableViewCell is too long so am trying to update it and then move another component closer to the label so they are next to each other.

I basically want to calculate the width of the label based upon the text length, make the label shorter then move a UIImageView next to it closer so you always have the UILabel + UIImageView right next to each other without a big gap in-between even if the length of the text is different.

When i try to change the Width of the UILabel via code it doesn't take effect.

For example:

```
myLabel.Frame = new RectangleF ((float)myLabel.Frame.X, (float) myLabel.Frame.Y, (float) 2, (float) myLabel.Frame.Height);
```

Comment: Have you taken a look at using autolayout ?

Answer (score 0):

If your using Autolayout then this code will not take effect. You should either disable Autolayout or add constrains to your UILabel with Autolayout

[How to add Autolayout constrains with Xamarin](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/designer/designer_auto_layout/)